# Formato númerico inconsistente

Tags: r

sou um experiente programador em SAS, mas iniciante no R. Estou trabalhando com o RStudio Version 0.99.903 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc. e Windows 8. Estou com a seguinte dúvida:

1. O arquivo "a_us" possui 4 campos numericos e 2 alfanuméricos como se segue:

   > str(a_us) //comando para mostrar a estrutura do arquivo

> ```
> 'data.frame': 1039992 obs. of  7 variables:  
> $ 'dsSisOriginario'             : chr  "Construcard" "Construcard" "Construcard" "Construcard" ...  
> $ 'nrContrato'                  : chr "000002160000023630," "000002160000116565," "000002160000225267," ...  
> $ 'vlCredInadimplenciaLancadoCa': num  9570 4455 6791 2678 4483 ...  
> $ 'dtCredInadimplenciaEntradaCa': chr "03/11/2002" "17/10/2004" "25/03/2007" "15/12/2006" ...  
> $ 'vlCredFcvsCessao'            : num  271 216 329 130 217 ...  
> $ PercentPagoCarteira           : num  0.0283 0.0484 0.0484 0.0484 ...  
> $ QtdCredDiasAtraso             : int  5110 4396 3507 3607 2768 2407 2640 ...
> ```

2. Utilizando o summary(a_us) o resultado sai como esperado, isto é, as estatísticas para as variáveis numéricas estão perfeitas.
3. Contudo, quando tento tirar, por exemplo, a média (mean())  ou qualquer outro procedimento quantitativo, como hist(), dessas mesmas variáveis numéricas ('vlCredInadimplenciaLancadoCa', 'vlCredFcvsCessao', PercentPagoCarteira, QtdCredDiasAtraso), funciona somente para as variáveis (PercentPagoCarteira, QtdCredDiasAtraso), para as outras ('vlCredInadimplenciaLancadoCa', 'vlCredFcvsCessao'), recebo a mensagem:

> ```
> > mean(a_us$'vlCredFcvsCessao')
> >     [1] NA
> >     Warning message:
> >     In mean.default(a_us$vlCredFcvsCessao) :
> >       argumento não é numérico nem lógico: retornando NA
> ```

Apesar da variável ser numérica, eu recebo essa mensagem de erro!

Alguém pode me dar um dica do que é que está acontecendo e como resolver isso?

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou a sua pergunta, mas a formatação dela está bem confusa e um tanto difícil de ser arrumada. Com isso, fica difícil responder a sua pergunta porque isso compromete a compreensão do formato de dados, que é fundamental para que alguém possa respondê-la. Entretanto, como não conheço nada de R, não tenho muito como ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que seus dados foram importados, algumas colunas ficaram com aspas no nome. Isso impede o operador `$` de funcionar da forma que você esperava. A melhor forma de corrigir é re-importar a base. Mas também é possível se referir à coluna desta forma:

```
mean(a_us$`'vlCredFcvsCessao'`)
```

Note o acento que está *envolvendo* o nome da coluna.

Veja este simples exemplo:

```
> df <- dplyr::data_frame("'colunacomaspas'" = 1, colunasemaspas = 1)
> str(df)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ 'colunacomaspas': num 1
 $ colunasemaspas  : num 1
> mean(df$`'colunacomaspas'`)
[1] 1
> mean(df$'colunacomaspas')
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: Unknown column 'colunacomaspas' 
2: In mean.default(df$colunacomaspas) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Veja que o `str` mostra de forma diferente o nome das colunas com aspas e das sem aspas no seu exemplo também.

Outra forma de corrigir seria renomear as colunas retirando essas aspas. Exemplo:

```
> names(df) <- gsub("'", "", names(df))
> mean(df$colunacomaspas)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Obrigado Daniel, era isso mesmo. Importei do MS Access, mas não tenho ideia do porquê de ele colocar essas aspas. De qualquer forma, o problema foi resolvido. Valeu!

Comment: @Marcelo que bom que deu certo! Essas aspas é difícil de descobrir mesmo...

Answer (score 0):

Vou seguir o padrão de queixa de um bom número de colaboradores da versão em inglês :). É fundamental para que possamos tentar reproduzir o problema que você coloque um trecho da rotina R que possa ser facilmente copiada e colada para outros ambientes e então comparada pelas pessoas que tentam te ajudar. Também importante citar a versão do R, se está usando RStudio ou não e a versão do sistema operacional

Como não existe um exemplo do data frame aqui vai um pequeno exemplo de possibilidades de referência as colunas do data frame e de como você pode enviar mais detalhes sobre o seu problema, não é uma resposta, ainda. "Aparentemente" está tudo perfeito.

```
df <- data.frame(a= seq(1:10),b=seq(11:20))
summary(df)

# testar a classe de uma coluna
class(df$a)

mean(df$a)
mean(df[,'a'])
mean(df$'a')
```

Comment: Obrigado jcarlos, fiz uma edição da pergunta e acho que deve estar mais clara. Estou aprendendo a mexer na edição do texto aqui neste ambiente. De qualquer forma, meu problema é que algumas variáveis numéricas não são reconhecidas como numéricas. Já passou por este problemas?

Comment: Oi @marcelo o Daniel já te respondeu :). Não deixe de marcar a resposta dele como a aceita. É outro procedimento que com frequência nos esquecemos qdo iniciantes no stackoverflow.